# Issue with values Formik

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik

> GitHub discussion about this issue - https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/529

I passed formik values to a function that is called in `<Field/>`'s onChange but when I type in the `<Field/>`, the last character does not fall into the function.

**CodeSandbox** - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-moon-zqfde)

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Minimal Code Instance**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";

function App() {
  //------ HERE ----------
  const getValues = values => console.log(values.fields[0]);
  //----------------------
  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ fields: [""] }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
          console.log(values);
          return false;
        }}
        render={({ setFieldValue, values }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray
              name="fields"
              render={() => (
                <Field
                  type="text"
                  name="fields.0"
                  placeholder="Write something"
                  onChange={e => {
                    setFieldValue("fields.0", e.target.value);
                    //---------------
                    getValues(values);
                    //---------------
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I think its an issue with setFieldValue. See https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/529 . It uses setState internally, but does not return a callback, where we can call another function , like setState does. The suggestions in that page are not working out for the codeSandbox you have linked. You may have to think of having your own state to manage that input, if this requirement is essential.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not familiar with formik and I just took a quick look on the implementation.
But here's my two cents on the issue.

**Why are the values not updating after each call?**

You are trying to get the values before the rerendering is happening and the value you have is the old one always, because the component is not updated yet.

To verify try to add `console.log(values.fields[0]);` in the App component before the getValue definition.

**Why is the call happening before the rerendering?**

The `onChange` implementation will trigger the `handleChange` in which it's a memoized function call that will not be triggered if you have the same value BUT you changed the value.

`handleChange` will be triggered if the `executeChange` value is different and `executeChange` also memoized that depends on `setFieldValue` or the `state.values`.

`setFieldValue` is an event callback that only update the ref after each render. That's from formik docs `// we copy a ref to the callback scoped to the current state/props on each render` and that didn't happen yet in your case -`useEventCallback`-.

Once the state is updated by the action then your component will be updated but your function is not called yet.

`setFieldValue` will try to validate the input and return a promise and bubble that up to `executeChange` and `handleChange` and it treats that as a low priority so it's not a blocking call.

**A quick solution might be is to use `onKeyUp` instead of `onChange` I think that will bypass the `useCallback` and actually updates the component with higher priority call**

```
function App({ values, setFieldValue }) {
  console.log("Rerendering",values.fields[0])
  //------ HERE ----------
  const getValues = () => console.log(values.fields[0]);
  //----------------------

  return (
    <div className="formik-wrapper">
      <Form>
        <FieldArray
          name="fields"
          render={() => (
            <Field
              type="text"
              name="fields.0"
              placeholder="Write something"
              onKeyUp={e => {
                setFieldValue("fields.0", e.target.value);
                getValues();
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope this can help or at least lead for some help.

[Check formik implementation](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/src/Formik.tsx)

Answer (score 20):

This answer is based on Formik v1.5.7

You are trying to get stale value of `values` in your code right after calling `setFieldValue` which is internally doing async operation so you cant expect values being changed right after it (call) returns. Thus when you try to log value out of `values` you get state object during current (running) render cycle.

When the `values` do change, Formik re-renders the form in which it will have desired value that you are trying to get.

I moved up the code in your example to explain this.

Here's the [updated code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nc0ys).

Since this question is updated after my answer, I'll comment about this specific [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/529).  The issue is in enhancement development request and solutions in the comments will not work in your example as `values` will still be "OLD" values.

Here's the reason why `async` `await` solution will not work in this case:

```
onChange={async e => {
    await setFieldValue("fields.0", e.target.value);
    getValues(values);
}}
```

Above code upon click event `awaits` on function called `setFieldValue` which gets executed and internally sets state which is async operation placed in the execution stack. Call returns and `console.log` logs `values` which happens to be existing render cycle `values`.

Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a reliable way to get the latest state of Formik values, right after setting a Field's value & trigger another method/function/event based on this 'new' set of values. The obvious hindrance here is that `setFieldValue()` is an asynchronous method that internally uses `setState()` & hence there is no direct way to achieve this in a way you described / expected.

- I wouldn't recommend the workarounds (setTimeout, random await just to bypass the nextTick, etc) mentioned in the github issue (https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/529) since they are non-deterministic.
- One way that worked for me is using `componentDidUpdate` (or any other comparable React Lifecycle method) and listening for change in the props.
- Formik exposes the field values in React component's props at `this.props.values`
- When you use `componentDidUpdate`, you just would need to compare the previous props to new props to check if something has changed.

Here is a minimal code to show what I mean.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

class Sample extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(!_.isEqual(prevProps.values, this.props.values)) {
      // At least one of the Formik fields have changed. And this.props.values holds this newest data about of the fields.
      triggerWhateverWithNewValues(this.props.values);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getValues`, it gets old value as `setFieldValue` Function call is not finished(so value is not set to `Field.0`). you can directly pass the Value to Function `getValues` though.

```
const getValues = valueField => console.log(valueField);


onChange={e => {
    setFieldValue("fields.0", e.target.value);
    getValues(e.target.value);
}}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-water-ixuuk

Comment: yeah I know but I need to pass values array to getValues() anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar problem connected to `setFieldValue` and `setFieldTouched`.
Before that I had function like this

```
onSelect={(value) => {
            setFieldTouched('vendor.id', true)
            policyTextAreaRef.current?.updateValue(value?.policy ?? '')
            setFieldValue('vendor', value)
            setFieldValue('policy', value?.policy ?? '')
          }}
```

But as it is described above I was always getting previous value not actual one . So workaround to that was making async function and adding `await Promise.resolve()` . Here is the working solution for me :

```
onSelect={async (value) => {
            setFieldTouched('vendor.id', true)
            await Promise.resolve()
            policyTextAreaRef.current?.updateValue(value?.policy ?? '')
            setFieldValue('vendor', value)
            setFieldValue('policy', value?.policy ?? '')
          }}
```