# Formik setValues doesnt work with number type input

Tags: reactjs, input, numbers, formik

So im using Formik and ive got a couple of actions where the values in formik should be overwritten. since i have to overwrite all values i use the setValues function and it does its job. but i got an input field of type number, which doesnt show the right value since its always staying with 0. and when i submit the form it takes the right value which i set with setValues but isnt shown in the input field.
why does it work perfectly fine with text fields but not with numbers?

this is the input field

```
<Form.Control
    type="number"
    min="0"
    step="0.01"
    data-number-to-fixed="2"
    data-number-stepfactor="100"
    name={getNameFor(values, "tariffVersionPrice", "optionVersionPrice")}
    defaultValue={getValueFor(values, "tariffVersionPrice", "optionVersionPrice")}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your ```min```, ```step```, etc be a numbers, not strings?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use setValue then?

Comment: setValues(new TariffVersion({
...
price: selectedVersion.tariffVersionPrice,
....
}));
as i said: when i look into the values after that, the price is set right, but not shown in the input field

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613496/issue-with-values-formik

Comment: thats not my problem. the values in the other input fields i set in the same setValues call are perfectly fine (they are all regular text inputs) but the number thing isnt working.

Comment: even when i try it with numbers instead of strings, it doesnt work:
min={0}
step={0.01}
data-number-to-fixed={2}
data-number-stepfactor={100}

Comment: Can you create minimally reproducible example on code sanbox? It would be easier to help you as the code snippet you are showing does not even have the setValue

Comment: sry, dont know how to do it. never worked with code sandbox before. its basically only a form controlled by formik with a few text inputs and a single number input. next to it is a small table which contains the versions of which i want to load the information into the form either by dblClicking the row or selecting the row and then click a button to copy the values into the form. either way setValues is called and works for the text inputs, but not for the number. really cant understand why this happens...